# Arraylist is not returning the object

Tags: java, arraylist

I dunno where I am missing the concept, I have coded for small project which maintains contacts using java arraylist and GUI. There are add, delete,seach,first,last,previous,next,exit,clear buttons in the application. All buttons except first and last everything is working fine. problem where I am getting is in the function Displayfirst**()

Here is the code

AddressBookDemo.java

```
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        if (e.getSource () == jbbSave){
             savePerson();
             clear(); 
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnDelete){
             deletePerson();
             clear();
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnFirst){
             displayFirstRecord();

                    clear(); 
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnLast){
             displayLastRecord();
             clear(); 
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnSearch){
             searchPerson();
        } 

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnForward){
             displayNextRecord(); 
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnBack){
            displayPreviousRecord();
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnClear){
            clear();
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == jbnExit){         
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
      public void searchPerson() {

        name = jtfName.getText();
        name = name.toUpperCase();
        /*clear contents of arraylist if there are any from previous search*/
        personsList.clear();



        if(name.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter person name to search.");
        }
        else{
            /*get an array list of searched persons using PersonDAO*/
            personsList = pDAO.searchPerson(name);

            if(personsList.size() == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No records found.");
                //Perform a clear if no records are found.
                clear();
            }
            else
            {
                /*downcast the object from array list to PersonInfo*/
                PersonInfo person = (PersonInfo) personsList.get(0);

                 // displaying search record in text fields 
                jtfName.setText(person.getName());
                jtfAddress.setText(person.getAddress());
                jtfPhone.setText(""+person.getPhone());
                jtfEmail.setText(person.getEmail());
            }
        }

     }
****
public void displayFirstRecord(){

         // dec in recordNumber to display previous person info, already 
         //stored in personsList during search                  


        if(pDAO.getpersonsList().size() == 0 ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no records"); 

            /*if user has reached the begining of results, disable back button*/
            jbnForward.setEnabled(true);
            jbnBack.setEnabled(false);

             // inc by one to counter last dec

        }else{

                        System.out.println(pDAO.getpersonsList().size());
       personsList = pDAO.getpersonsList();
     PersonInfo person=(PersonInfo)personsList.get(0);
            // displaying search record in text fields 
            jtfName.setText(person.getName());
            jtfAddress.setText(person.getAddress());
            jtfPhone.setText(""+person.getPhone());
            jtfEmail.setText(person.getEmail());
                        //jbnFirst.setEnabled(false);
        }

     }

public void displayLastRecord(){

         // dec in recordNumber to display previous person info, already 
         //stored in personsList during search                  


        if(pDAO.getpersonsList().size()== 0 ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no records"); 

            /*if user has reached the begining of results, disable back button*/
            jbnForward.setEnabled(true);
            jbnBack.setEnabled(false);

             // inc by one to counter last dec
                    }else{
            jbnForward.setEnabled(true);
            PersonInfo person = (PersonInfo) pDAO.getpersonsList().get(pDAO.getpersonsList().size()-1);

            // displaying search record in text fields 
            jtfName.setText(person.getName());
            jtfAddress.setText(person.getAddress());
            jtfPhone.setText(""+person.getPhone());
            jtfEmail.setText(person.getEmail());
        }

     }

********************
```

PersonDAO.Java

```
public class PersonDAO{      


    private ArrayList<PersonInfo> personsList;

*******************************


    public ArrayList searchPerson(String name)
    {
            ArrayList<PersonInfo> personsList1=new ArrayList<>();

            for (PersonInfo personsList2 : personsList) {
                PersonInfo p = (PersonInfo) personsList2;
                if(p.getName() == null ? name == null : p.getName().equals(name)){
                    personsList1.add(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
         return personsList1;
            }
```

PersonInfo.Java

```
Contains a person class.
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? You telling us you have an issue doesn't give us much, mate. Please give us an output example so we can see what the error is

Comment: No idea what the problem is, you need to be more specific. Also, you seem to have added *all* the code rather than only what is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Don't just dump your full code and ask for debugging. Instead take your time and try to limit your code to [minimum which is needed to reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). Remember that "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.*"

Comment: Pshemo this is the first I am using , I will follow these rulez from next time. when I post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `clear()` method which clears the text of the `JLable`s

```
else if (e.getSource() == jbnFirst){
    displayFirstRecord();
    clear(); 
}
else if (e.getSource() == jbnLast){
    displayLastRecord();
    clear(); 
}
```

....

```
public void displayFirstRecord(){

    ....

    jtfName.setText(person.getName());
    jtfAddress.setText(person.getAddress());
    jtfPhone.setText(""+person.getPhone());
    jtfEmail.setText(person.getEmail());

    ....
 }
```

....  The `displayLastRecord()` method does mostly the same thing.

```
public void clear(){
    jtfName.setText("");
    jtfAddress.setText("");
    jtfPhone.setText("");
    jtfEmail.setText("");

    ....
 }
```

Comment: How silly, I missed that part . Thanks a lot  Titus. Now I have another problem with search function , it is not returning the records always it is displaying no record found error. It works well when there is one record.

Comment: public ArrayList searchPerson(String name)
*****         if(p.getName().equals(name))***** If condition is changed in PersonDAO.java . Now it is working fine.